# Android Stuck on Loading in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

I am facing a problem in my flutter project. Actually when I navigate to android from dropdown, It stuck on "Loading".

Please tell me how to solve it[image]

Comment: Did you try Invalidate Caches & Restart? and maybe try selecting "Project" by clicking Android just above loading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hurray!!
I solved it myself (feeling proud)

Actually you have to open **gradle-wrapper.properties** and click on **"open for editing in android studio"** and it will start downloading some files from internet

Once downloaded and synced. Restart Android studio and problem will be solved

please comment if you need any help

Comment: This is an annoying bug :(

Comment: What if "open for editing in android studio" doesn't show up on your gradle-wrapper.properties file? :(

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem

My issue was my project was **stuck in safe mode**. I navigated, using the project files tab, to the manifest file. Once opened, a banner came on that indicated '**Trust this project**' and '**Stay in Safe Mode**'. I simply selected '**Trust this project**', it synced an all was well. Went back to the projects tab and from the dropdown list I selected **android**.

Hope this helps someone. Kept my head buzzing for a while

Answer (score 0):

First time user of Android Studio, and I know it is stupid, but I this issue as well when I created a "hello world" app for the first time on the IDE. For me, I discovered that I just need to switch to the `Project` in the dropdown thingy.

I hope it helps

[image]